# Cannot find mistake in my "Combination Sum" solution

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem can be found here [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/).
I am breaking my head over where is my mistake and why my solution does not produce proper output. I spent hours on this and still cannot understand. Can anyone help?
My problem is somewhere in the last 2 lines of `_rec` function where I am trying to account on condition that adding the same item from array multiple times is allowed.

My solution:

```
class Solution:
    def _rec(self, arr, sums, i, all_arrs):
        if sums == 0:
            all_arrs.append(arr[i+1:])
            return
        
        if sums < 0 or i < 0:
            return

        #we can include current number at index i 
        withi = self._rec(arr, sums-arr[i], i-1, all_arrs) 
        
        #or not include it
        arr_copy = arr.copy()
        arr_copy.pop(i) # since we delete higher indices it won't affect lower indices 
        withouti = self._rec(arr_copy, sums, i-1, all_arrs)
        
        #to account on "The same repeated number may be chosen from candidates unlimited number of times."
        arr.append(arr[i])
        repeati = self._rec(arr, sums-arr[i], i, all_arrs)
        
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        final_arr = []
        self._rec(candidates, target, len(candidates)-1, final_arr)
        return final_arr
```

Problem
Given a set of candidate numbers (candidates) (without duplicates) and a target number (target), find all unique combinations in candidates where the candidate numbers sums to target.

**The same repeated number may be chosen from candidates unlimited number of times.**

Note:

All numbers (including target) will be positive integers.
The solution set must not contain duplicate combinations.
Example 1:

Input: `candidates = [2,3,6,7], target = 7,`
A solution set is:

```
[
  [7],
  [2,2,3]
]
```

Example 2:

Input: candidates = [2,3,5], target = 8,
A solution set is:

```
[
  [2,2,2,2],
  [2,3,3],
  [3,5]
]
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= candidates.length <= 30
1 <= candidates[i] <= 200
Each element of candidate is unique.
1 <= target <= 500


Output
[[7],[2,3,3,2],[3,3,2,2],[2,3,2,2,3,2,2],[3,2,2,3,2,2,2],[7]]

Expected
[[2,2,3],[7]]
```

Note: I know it can be optimized with dynamic programming, but I just wanted for now to make recursion work.

Comment: When you walked through it by hand with pencil and paper or with a debugger did you find any statement or expression or result that looked suspicious? Were intermediate values/data what you expected?

Comment: Why is your solution a class?

Comment: `withi`, `withouti`, and `repeati` are never used or assigned to anything since the `_rec` function doesn't return any value. also I don't know why you are making a copy of the array and popping `i` from it. this doesn't seem to do anything useful

Comment: `I just wanted for now to make recursion work.` - You have written a recursive procedure that is an iterative process. You could try to write it as an iterative procedure and getting it to work might be easier - then refactor to the recursive procedure.

Comment: One thing that may be complicating your effort is that you have decided to use slices of  and modify the original `candidates`. You are *carrying-all-your-baggage* with you on each recursion anyway, why not construct a tuple that contains the current items that have been accumulated and pass that down the recursion path.

Comment: @wwii I am not completely clear regarding your suggestion. Could you clarify what tuple consists of? The idea is to basically pass down the array of items so far selected, if I delete an item then I create new object, if I dont delete an item I am passing the argument down the recursion

Answer (score -1):

instead of always going to the next number in the array, only go to the next number once the target sum is met or exceeded.

so in the case of 2,3,5 and 8 you get

```
2 = 2
2+2 = 4
2+2+2 = 6
2+2+2+2 = 8
```

got an answer, now try the next number

```
2+2+2+3 = 9
```

too big, try the next number

```
2+2+2+5 = 11
```

etc

full loop would be something like

```
2
2+2
2+2+2
2+2+2+2 met
2+2+2+3 exceeded
2+2+2+5 exceeded
2+2+3
2+2+3+3 exceeded (don't do 2 again since we already tried 2+2+2+3 which would be the same)
2+2+3+5 exceeded
2+2+5 exceeded
2+3
2+3+3 met
2+3+5 exceeded
2+5
2+5+5 exceeded
3
3+3
3+3+3 exceeded
3+3+5 exceeded
3+5 met
5
5+5 exceeded
complete
```

Comment: Are you implying that the function needs an extensive refactor or if there is an easy fix *to-the-code* did you figure out what it is?

Comment: you probably need a refactor. i just tried the script you provided and as output I get `[3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3]` which seems far off from the expected output.

Comment: So is this an answer to the question?

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you as this appears to be a school assignment. But I hope at least a written out path your program should likely be taking may help you out.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm just trying to figure out if you have provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and if not whether you can salvage it.

Comment: I believe I have. The question is how to use the same number any number of times. The solution I stated is to keep trying the same number before iterating to the next one, with a walk through of how that would look.

Comment: it is not a school assignment it is a leet code question, there are plenty of answers in discussion section, I just could not figure out what is the issue with my solution and it does not seem like you have an answer